# Do cover providing powers provide cover from adjacent melee attacks?

Tags: dnd-4e, cover, zone, warden

My Warden just acquired the level 2 Utility Daily: `Nature's Abundance` which creates a `Zone` which provides `Cover` in a Burst 3 for me and my allies (AWESOME!). To make sure that I fully understand the mechanics of this skill, I need to know if this skill will provide my allies and me cover from adjacent melee attacks.

Does a `Zone` providing `Cover` derived from a power provide cover from adjacent melee attacks? The power states:

> You and your allies have cover while within the Zone.

Comment: yes, cover for allies in burst 3 is awesome :)

Comment: Does it count as Partial Cover or Total Cover?

Comment: @Scott Your question inspired me to make this post: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/20034/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If that's how it's written and there's no errata on it right now, that's how it should work.  Cover is cover is cover, no matter if it's ranged or melee.

Comment: Just to provide an additional little bit of feedback, I think any sort of concealment/cover in D&D has always worked in hand-to-hand or ranged combat, even if a foe is within the area of effect (excepting, of course, mundane visible cover)